# Number of operands to take when evaluating postfix notation?

Tags: efficiency, mathematical-programming

- All sources I have seen list taking two operands from the stack once we encounter an operator.
- Why? What if not all of my operators are binary (taking two arguments)? What if I have custom unary and ternary operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess those sources innately assume binary operators. In a stack-based language (like postfix math notation) an $n$-ary operator takes $n$ items from the top of the stack as its input. Constants are often also viewed as arity 0, or *nullary* operators in this context.

Comment: I guess I would need a table to specify n-arity of each operator; so that the stack is processed accordingly when a specific operator is encountered.